# Parallelize a process on several servers with EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I'm using Glassfish 3.1 and JEE6. What I would like to do is so parallelize a long CPU process on several servers.
If by example, I have 1000 images and 10 servers, I would like each server processes 100 images and return the results to the "master".

My first thought is at each request, I call the remote EJB (asynchronous) from each servers with the images to process as parameter and wait the result. Is it possible to call for different machines the same remote EJB?
Problem with this method is I have to set manually the list of all servers. If I want to remove or add one, I have to deployed again the application. I would like to use a method more dynamic.

Using JMS could be a better idea? If so, how to do it? The master creates a queue, and each "worker" machine, can access to this queue. The master doesn't need to know the ip of each "worker" machine. Problem is, the master will not know how many workers there are and in how many parts he has to split the images to process...

Other idea is to use Hadoop, but I mostly know nothing about it...

I would like to have some advice from you, what is the best way to do it in a JEE6 application?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, your schema pushes work to each of the workers. It's generally better to add work to a queue, and have the workers pull from the queue each time they finish a task.

Maybe consider Celery for it - http://www.celeryproject.org/ (Since you're using Jelastic, you might like to know that this can be installed on a Jelastic VDS)

Comment: Thank you a lot, I will take a look into it.
Something important I forgot to mention is the process has to be synchrone: client send a request for comparing images, tasks are dispatched to several workers, results are merged and immediately sent back to the client. Is it possible to do that with Celery?

Comment: Celery is asynchronous, but that's only about the distribution of the work. If the workers are available (enough spare capacity) they should still be able to return the results quickly. I suppose in any case you would need the client to loop for a while (polling to see if the final merged result is ready, or if they need to wait longer).